# AlarmManager Dont Work ni cant put the manifest part

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

plis. i am making an AlarmManager for the porpuse of repeatting the action in 1 minute (in the background ), but it doesnt work, anyone can help me?
MY  principal activity

```
      int repeatTime = 60;  //Repeat alarm time in seconds
        AlarmManager processTimer = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, onBackround.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//Repeat alarm every second
        processTimer.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),repeatTime*1000, pendingIntent);`
```

MY BROADCOAST RECIEVED:

```
     package com.example.hatzalahrescatista;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class onBackround extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Do something every 1 MINUTE
    }
}`
```

MANIFEST (I CANT PUT THE  PERMISSION FOR THIS ALARMMANAGER) example:

()makes me an error like "unsolved class....."

````
```
 <application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"

    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".ActividadPrincipal">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.hatzalahrescatista_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActividadLogin">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


</application>
````

````
```
````

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare your receiver in Manifest file.
write this in your manifest file

```
   <receiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".onBackround "
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

*You have to create a service class that running in background.
and define which action you want to do.*

This is your broadcast receiver

```
   package com.example.hatzalahrescatista;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class onBackround extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 int repeatTime = 60;  //Repeat alarm time in seconds
        AlarmManager processTimer = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YOUR_SERVICE_CLASS_NAME.class); //create a service class and call here
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//Repeat alarm every second
        processTimer.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),repeatTime*1000, pendingIntent);    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Android document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), AlarmManager is inexact

> These alarms can significantly impact the power use of the device when idle (and thus cause significant battery blame to the app scheduling them), so they should be used with care. To reduce abuse, there are restrictions on how frequently these alarms will go off for a particular application. Under normal system operation, it will not dispatch these alarms more than about every minute (at which point every such pending alarm is dispatched); when in low-power idle modes this duration may be significantly longer, such as 15 minutes.

So if you want your job execute exactly once per minute, I suggest using the [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long))